# pipenv consistently failing to install pyscopg2

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2, pipenv

Is there some magic trick to get `pipenv` to install `psycopg2`?

My `Pipfile` looks like this:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
django = "==2.1.3"
psycopg2 = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

I've tried adding and taking away an install of pyscopg2-binary, but it makes no difference. I am on a Mac running OSX 10.14.4.

Here is the output I get after running `pipenv install`:

```
An error occurred while installing psycopg2==2.8.3 --hash=sha256:128d0fa910ada0157bba1cb74a9c5f92bb8a1dca77cf91a31eb274d1f889e001 --hash=sha256:227fd46cf9b7255f07687e5bde454d7d67ae39ca77e170097cdef8ebfc30c323 --hash=sha256:2315e7f104681d498ccf6fd70b0dba5bce65d60ac92171492bfe228e21dcc242 --hash=sha256:4b5417dcd2999db0f5a891d54717cfaee33acc64f4772c4bc574d4ff95ed9d80 --hash=sha256:640113ddc943522aaf71294e3f2d24013b0edd659b7820621492c9ebd3a2fb0b --hash=sha256:897a6e838319b4bf648a574afb6cabcb17d0488f8c7195100d48d872419f4457 --hash=sha256:8dceca81409898c870e011c71179454962dec152a1a6b86a347f4be74b16d864 --hash=sha256:b1b8e41da09a0c3ef0b3d4bb72da0dde2abebe583c1e8462973233fd5ad0235f --hash=sha256:cb407fccc12fc29dc331f2b934913405fa49b9b75af4f3a72d0f50f57ad2ca23 --hash=sha256:d3a27550a8185e53b244ad7e79e307594b92fede8617d80200a8cce1fba2c60f --hash=sha256:f0e6b697a975d9d3ccd04135316c947dd82d841067c7800ccf622a8717e98df1! Will try again.
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 7/7 — 00:00:45
Installing initially failed dependencies…
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26_2/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1874, in do_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       keep_outdated=keep_outdated
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/

............
...........

6m-darwin.so', '    ld: library not found for -lssl', '    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)', "    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1", '    ----------------------------------------', 'ERROR: Command "/Users/mdd/.local/share/virtualenvs/justfacts-2tIl3QYb/bin/python3 -u -c \'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__=\'"\'"\'/private/var/folders/jz/s0hyvf2n5yd8glg82gphcn9h0000gp/T/pip-install-f6uqfqa9/psycopg2/setup.py\'"\'"\';f=getattr(tokenize, \'"\'"\'open\'"\'"\', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace(\'"\'"\'\\r\\n\'"\'"\', \'"\'"\'\\n\'"\'"\');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, \'"\'"\'exec\'"\'"\'))\' install --record /private/var/folders/jz/s0hyvf2n5yd8glg82gphcn9h0000gp/T/pip-record-k9xlsee0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/mdd/.local/share/virtualenvs/justfacts-2tIl3QYb/bin/../include/site/python3.6/psycopg2" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/jz/s0hyvf2n5yd8glg82gphcn9h0000gp/T/pip-install-f6uqfqa9/psycopg2/']
```

I've tried the recommended commands, such as `pipenv clean`, even tried everything from scratch in new directory and no `Pipfile`, but no luck. When I attempt to install psycopg2 directly via `pipenv install pyscopg2`, same result.

Comment: The `ssl` library is missing. Try `brew install openssl` and then run the `pipenv` command again.

Comment: @heemayl just confirmed that openssl is already installed.

Comment: Try `brew unlink openssl && brew link openssl --force`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expanding on heemayl's comment, I ultimately needed to run:

```
brew unlink openssl && brew link openssl --force
```

Then setup a bunch of environment variables:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

Then delete the `Pipfile.lock` and reinstall everything again, but initially skipping the lock file creation via `pipenv install --skip-lock` and then recreate the lock file with `pipenv lock`

Comment: Thanks, this helped me too. Would you mind marking this question as answered/solved? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 5):

For me, running Ubuntu 20.04 running under WSL2 I had to follow the instructions [here](https://www.psycopg.org/install/)

`sudo apt install python3-dev libpq-dev`

then I ran `pipenv shell` to start up my environment.

Then running: `pip install psycopg2` ran without issue.

Comment: Interesting, so did you have any reference to psycopg2 in your Pipfile or is it left as a silent dependency?

Comment: @combinatorist - later I added it to my requirements.txt as `psycopg2-binary`

Answer (score 2):

You are unable to build it. Try installing this instead: https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/

Comment: How do you suggest installing? With `pipenv`?

Comment: Yes. Set it as a dependency as you would any other package.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this exact problem. I had to remove my current virtualenv and rebuild it.

```
pipenv --rm
rm Pipfile.lock
pipenv install
```